# iPads in the corporate world

Tags: ipad, network

Is anyone using an iPad in the corporate world? If you are:

- Is it better than carrying around a laptop, and if so, how?
- Do iPads connect to networks like notebooks do?
- Can I remote into my Windows PC in a corporate environment using an iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I, personally, haven't had any experience using the iPad in a corporate setting, there are a couple people in my company who are using it in a lot of meetings and seem to be perfetly happy with it for lightweight tasks: taking notes in meetings, quick responses to emails, and the like. Your mileage may vary.

I'm pretty sure the iPad only has the wifi and 3G and I'm not aware of any LAN connectivity unless someone has sorted out an app for that (something like Apple's iDisk app.)

There are several remote access apps out there, LogMeIn has one that comes to mind but that costs a quite a bit of money. My friend uses that and really likes it a lot. but this is to log into a specific machine, not just jump onto network like a laptop would.

Comment: Wi-Fi isn't necessarily any different from LAN. Corporate Wi-Fi can be on the same subnet as all of their wired ethernet. The question is what network resources exist and can the iPad connect to them.

Comment: Who downvotes a three year old, clearly outdated, answer?

Answer (score 5):

- Yes, it is indeed better than carrying around a laptop, because it is lighter, faster and instant-on "computer". Also great for taking notes during the meetings, answering emails if that is the sort of thing you do. The typing may be a bit difficult if you are too much used to the normal keyboard. Of course, you can attach the Bluetooth keyboard.
- As Philip pointed out, iPad has Wifi, so you shouldn't be having any problems connecting to Wifi network, if your office has one. Also, with 3G you can stay connected even when you don't have the Wifi.
- About the Remote Connection, iPad supports VPN networking if that is needed, and there are several applications on iPad that allow you to use it as a Remote Desktop. But I think it might be difficult thing to get used to - using touchscreen to control the mouse etc.

If you're on an environment which doesn't need custom applications that run on Windows/Computer, and you can get all your work done by just email and the browser, yes iPad can replace your netbook.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes - lighter and better battery life
2. Yes
3. Yes

Answer (score 0):

There are enterprise resources and IT department tools for managing a fleet of iPads (and iPhones) as business computers, on the premises or on the road. If your needs are such, you can also investigate having your in-house programmers develop your own custom apps to enable your employees to use iPads to work with your company's databases. Ask at your local Apple Store or look for someone in the [Apple Consultants Network](http://consultants.apple.com/).