# Can I remote desktop into a Windows-based corporate network from my iPad?

Tags: ipad, network, remote-desktop

> **Possible duplicate:**
>           [iPads in the corporate world](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2912/ipads-in-the-corporate-world)

Has anyone remote desktop into a Windows-based corporate network with an iPad? What has been your experience? How do you address the issue of multiple domains? Is this even possible?

Currently, I just connect my laptop to a network cable and remote desktop from one domain into another domain to get to my desktop computer into a different location.

Is this possible with an iPad? How would my regular network cable connect to an iPad?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re talking about accessing a Remote Desktop via a RDC Client, There are a lot of applications that work fine. I’m personally using [iTap Mobile](http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/itap-rdp-remote-desktop-for/id317062064?mt=8) RDP and it’s fantastic.

Comment: I think he wants something else, he wants your experience about RDC and something else at the end, I don't get what exactly he means.

Comment: Yeah, the question is weird, but since the tag is iPad, I’m assuming he wants to access (via RDC) to a Windows Corporate network. My Experience is that iTap works fine and I don’t see the issue with multiple domains because you can select your domain when you log (or create multiple connections). Let’s see what the OP Says.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your networking question: You can connect an iPad to a computer, or to a Wi-Fi connection (or both), but you can't connect an Ethernet cable to an iPad.

Comment: Dori, I just googled and it may be possible. Please let me know otherwise. http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB442Z/A

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner You would also need the Camera Connection Kit for that to even have a chance of working, because the stock iPad doesn't have a usb port. USB keyboards work with the kit, but I doubt this would, since there would have to be drivers in iOS to support it.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner - if you read further down the page you linked to, there are two questions in the Q&A section about precisely this. And again, the answer is "No." In [Dear Aunt TUAW: Will my MacBook Air Ethernet adapter work with my iPad?](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/07/19/dear-aunt-tuaw-will-my-macbook-air-ethernet-adapter-work-with-m/), TUAW came to the same conclusion as well.